# How to print data into a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Following script couldn't print all of the outputs into the file (test.txt), how can I solve it? (It has printed only one 3-mer).

```
import random

def amino(length):    
    return ''.join(random.choice('GPAVLIMCFYWHKRQNEDST') for i in range(length))

list_size = 8000    
for j in range(list_size):    
    drd = int(random.normalvariate(3, 0))    
    f = open('gen.dat', 'w')    
    print amino(drd)        
    f.write(amino(drd))
    f.close()
```

Comment: I try to get the same printed output into the file.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file with `'w'` mode, you are actually overwriting the file, if it already exists.

And you are opening the file and closing it inside the loop , hence the file would only contain the last `peptide(aminoacidDRG)` . You should open the file outside the loop, and use `with` statement for handling files, so that `with` statement can deal with closing the file, once the `with` block ends.

Example -

```
import random

def peptide(length):    
    return ''.join(random.choice('GPAVLIMCFYWHKRQNEDST') for i in range(length))

list_size = 8000
with open('gen.dat', 'w') as f:
    for j in range(list_size):    
        aminoacidDRG = int(random.normalvariate(3, 0))    
        print peptide(aminoacidDRG)        
        f.write(peptide(aminoacidDRG))
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep opening and closing the file each loop, only open it once

```
f = open('gen.dat', 'w')  
for j in range(list_size):    
    aminoacidDRG = int(random.normalvariate(3, 0))      
    print peptide(aminoacidDRG)        
    f.write(peptide(aminoacidDRG) + '\n')
f.close()
```

When you open a file with `'w'` it will overwrite if that file already exists. You could use `'a'` to append, but I would suggest the above code where you open the file only once and keep writing to it. You can save having to close the file by using a `with` statement

```
with open('gen.dat', 'w') as f:
    for j in range(list_size):    
        aminoacidDRG = int(random.normalvariate(3, 0))      
        print peptide(aminoacidDRG)        
        f.write(peptide(aminoacidDRG) + '\n')
```